# Helper method to produce list of selected users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, helper

I'm a beginner trying out some aspects pertaining to enrollments in my rails app. Users have many enrollments; enrollments belong to a lesson; enrollments have many word_expositions and scrambled_words.

I wrote a helper method in the lessons controller to produce a list of enrolled users, to display in each lesson show page:

```
helper_method :enrolled_users
  def enrolled_users
    lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
    enrollments = lesson.enrollments
    enrolled_users = enrollments.map { |enrollment| enrollment.user }
  end
```

I am now trying to implement a completed_expos helper so that I can indicate next to each user whether they have completed the expositional component of my app. What I have is:

```
helper_method :completed_expos
  def completed_expos
    lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
    completed_expos = enrolled_users.map do |user|
      current_enrollment = lesson.enrollment_for(user)
      all_expos = current_enrollment.word_expositions
      all_expos.all? { |expos| expos.completed == true }
    end
  end
```

I would like to add a notice next to each listed user regarding whether they completed the expos. So what I tried is:

```
<% enrolled_users.each do |user| %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= user.username %></li>

    <% if completed_expos.include?(user)  %>
      completed
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

but the effect is that, although enrolled users are listed, there is no indication as to expo completion in those places where it should list it. How can I go about selecting this subgroup of users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can get from your code is that your "completed_expos" method will always return an array of Boolean values (true, false) rather than a list of users, so it could never include the user you specify.

I guess what you might want to do was to use select instead of map.

```
enrolled_users.select do |user|
  current_enrollment = lesson.enrollment_for(user)
  all_expos = current_enrollment.word_expositions
  all_expos.all? { |expos| expos.completed == true }
end
```

Also, let me say that you don't need to assign the values in each of your methods to a variable with the same name as the method. Eg.

```
def enrolled_users
  lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  enrollments = lesson.enrollments
  enrolled_users = enrollments.map { |enrollment| enrollment.user }
end
```

Could be

```
def enrolled_users
  lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  enrollments = lesson.enrollments
  enrollments.map { |enrollment| enrollment.user }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the helper wasn't returning a user, as to map it into the array:

```
helper_method :completed_expos
def completed_expos
  lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
  completed_expos = enrolled_users.map do |user|
    current_enrollment = lesson.enrollment_for(user)
    all_expos = current_enrollment.word_expositions
    user if all_expos.all? { |expos| expos.completed == true }
  end
end
```